# Clone an email using the API: the email attribute _AdditionalEmailAttribute1 is not copied (SFMC)

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, email, soap, clone

We need your valuable help on SFMC.

We have a HubExchange app and a large client (millions of users) is using it and having some serious issues.

They have **Web Analytics Connector** enabled, which adds an extra attribute on their email called: `_AdditionalEmailAttribute1`

If you clone an email using the API (** see below how) the attribute is not copied.

If you do not mind, let us know if there is a way to make a copy that retains `_AdditionalEmailAttribute1`

Thanks,
Alex

We use this SFMC API call:

https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/email/

We clone the original email by giving these params:

`Name`

`CustomerKey`

`Subject`

`PreHeader`

`CategoryId` (our folder)

`ClonedFromID` (the original email)

Comment: The reply below does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It would be possible to retrieve the additional property and add it to the newly cloned email but it isn't brought over as part of the cloning process.

The SendAdditionalAttribute object can be used to retrieve the existing value used for AdditionalEmailAttribute1, then the same object can be used with the Update method to add that value to new email.

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/retrieving_additional_email_attributes/

Comment: Mac, we tried your suggestion. We can only get the additional attributes through the API if the email was already sent. We cannot get the additional attributes if the email was never sent (although the email was saved). If you do not mind, let us know what we can do to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

I've also struggled with this a bit, but managed to find out how to update the attributes. I felt there was a lack of documentation on how to update them.

You can update an Email object with SendAdditionalAttribute's:

```
// Create an Email instance or find an existing Email
// I'll simply update by an Email ID which I already know
var email = new Email();
email.ID = 114486; // Known ID of an Email
email.IDSpecified = true;

string requestId;
string overallStatus;
var results = _soapClient.Update(new UpdateOptions(), new APIObject[] { 
    new SendAdditionalAttribute() { 
        Email = email, 
        Name = "__AdditionalEmailAttribute1",   
        Value = "<some value>" 
    } 
}, out requestId, out overallStatus);

if (overallStatus == "OK")
{
    // Success
}
```

You can obviously change the **1** to any other index you want to update.